# POST request to users/sign_in is returning HTML and no response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, devise

I'm trying to get devise to work with my React front end. At the moment I have set up an AuthenticationService in the front end to sign users in. This is the first time I'm setting up devise with React so I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what.

[image: The API response]

The picture shows was I am getting when I console log the response from the API.

Here is what my authentication service looks like in the front end.

```
class AuthenticationService {
  async signIn(values) {
    return axios
      .get(`/users/sign_in`, { user: values })
      .then((response) => response.data)
  }
}

export default new AuthenticationService()
```

I have a Users::SessionsController that is empty and my front end looks like the code below. I am submitting a form with Formik, the values are correct when submitting the form and I am currently only console.logging the response to understand what data is being passed back from the AuthenticationService.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
  onSubmit={async (values) => {
    console.log("values", values)
    try {
      const response = await AuthenticationService.signIn(values)
      console.log("success?", response.success)
      if (response.success) {
        window.location.href = response.redirect
          ? console.log("response redirect")
          : console.log("/admin")
      }
    } catch {
      console.log("didn't work")
    }
  }}
>
```

this is what my routes look like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "api/dashboard#home"

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :dashboards
    resources :cookbooks
    resources :ingredients
    resources :recipes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise does not support API mode.
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4997

You might want to try [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem.

Or write your custom controllers to handle API requests correctly.
Hint: If you use `super`, you will end up response with html template or redirection to login page. So do not use them.
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers